# How to make the bot send a random message?

Tags: ruby

The method I'm using:

```
 when /random
        bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "TEXT GOES HERE", parse_mode: 'Markdown')
```

How do I make the bot send a **random** message (defined by me) when the user sends the `/random` command?

Thank you.

Comment: Telegram bot. 
gem 'telegram-bot-ruby'

Comment: You should probably specify what you mean by random message. Random combination of letters or words? Should they include random numbers as well ?

Comment: It depends on how you're going to define the random messages.  What exactly do you mean? You'll have a list  of random messages and you want to include one randomly?  Obviously, once you figure out how your random messages are defined, you'd replace "TEXT GOES HERE", probably with something like http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample

Answer (score 0):

As others said, it's not clear what you want.

If you want it to select random message from a list of predefined one try this:

```
messages = ['message one', 'message two', 'message three']
messages.sample
```

`Array#sample` returns random element of your array. You could achive it also this way: `messages[rand(messages.size)]`

BTW you forgot to quote "/random"